# Send value to parent then close child form, on event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a parent form with a combobox populated from a database, from which the user can select. The last value in the combo box is "add new", if the user selects this, a child form opens for the user to add a new value to the database. I have a button press event to add this value to the database, send the new `return value` to the parent and close the form. The parent should then select the new value from it's combo box and wait for the user to perform another action.

However, the code to send the `return value` to parent and close the form isn't working correctly. I `hide` the child, then call a function on it with the parent to access the `return value`. At this point the child form `shows` and the code stops before it runs another `hide` or `close`.

How can I fix this (code below)?

Parent Combobox event:

```
Private Sub cmbLocations_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbLocations.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        If cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = cmbLocations.Items.Count - 1 Then
            If diaAddLocation.IsAccessible = False Then diaAddLocation.Activate()
            diaAddLocation.RequestSender = Me
            diaAddLocation.ShowDialog()
            FillLocations()
            cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = LocationFromLocationName(diaAddLocation.formresult)
            diaAddLocation.Close()
            diaAddLocation.Dispose()
        Else
            bttYes.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Child Button Press and Return value function

```
Public Sub bttAddLOCtoDatabase_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttAddLOCtoDatabase.Click

    Dim LocationToBeAdded As String
    LocationToBeAdded = "'" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    AddLocation("'" & textbox1.Text & "'")
    FormResult = textbox1.Text
    GetLocations()
    frmFieldMaster.InitialiseNewParameter()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub


Public Function Result() As String
    Return FormResult
End Function
```

EDIT:

code with Steve's solution implemented:

```
Public Sub bttAddLOCtoDatabase_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttAddLOCtoDatabase.Click

    Dim LocationToBeAdded As String
    LocationToBeAdded = "'" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    AddLocation("'" & textbox1.Text & "'")
    FormResult = textbox1.Text
    GetLocations()
    frmFieldMaster.InitialiseNewParameter()
    DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    'me.Hide()

End Sub

Public Function Result() As String
    Return FormResult
    Me.Close()
End Function

Private Sub cmbLocations_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbLocations.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueTaken As Boolean = False
    If Not cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        If cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = cmbLocations.Items.Count - 1 Then
            Using diaaddlocation = New diaAddLocation
                diaaddlocation.requestsender = Me
                If DialogResult.OK = diaaddlocation.showdialog Then
                    FillLocations()
                    cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = LocationFromLocationName(diaaddlocation.result)
                    diaaddlocation.close()
                ElseIf DialogResult.Cancel = diaaddlocation.showdialog Then
                    cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = -1
                End If
            End Using
        Else
            bttYes.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run the code it enters `IF DialogResult.OK...` and opens the child. Then when I close the child the parent runs the next two lines of code and get the result from the child. After this the parent runs the line `IF DialogResult.OK...` again and stops with the child open. The code never reaches the `diaaddlocation.close` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all of this. You could try something like this

```
   If cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = cmbLocations.Items.Count - 1 Then
        Using diaAddLocation = new diaAddLocation()
             diaAddLocation.RequestSender = Me
             if DialogResult.OK = diaAddLocation.ShowDialog() then
                 FillLocations()
                 cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = LocationFromLocationName(diaAddLocation.formresult)
             End If
        End Using
   Else
       .....
```

This requires the `DialogResult` property for `bttAddLOCtoDatabase` set to `DialogResult.OK` and the child form `AcceptButton` property set to `bttAddLOCtoDatabase`. Now you could remove the Hide() call inside the `bttAddLOCtoDatabase_Click` method

This works because, until you don't exit the Using statement, your child form is still available to read its properties (results)

EDIT: Not related to the main problem, but these lines are wrong:

```
 ElseIf DialogResult.Cancel = diaaddlocation.showdialog Then
       cmbLocations.SelectedIndex = -1
```

you  should go with

```
  Using diaAddLocation = new diaAddLocation()
      diaAddLocation.RequestSender = Me
      Dim dr = diaAddLocation.ShowDialog()
      if dr = DialogResult.OK then
          ....
      else if dr = DialogResult.Cancel then
          ....
      end if
```

Comment: I have tried implementing this and I am still having similar problems. Within the `IF` condition the result is sent to the parent, but in the process the child closes and reopens.

Comment: What are you doing with FillLocations()? Could you show the code of that function? What happen if you temporarily remove the call to FillLocations(), set a breakpoint over cmbLocations.SelectedIndex and check the value for diaAddLocation.Results?

Comment: also the `LocationFromLocationName(diaaddlocation.result)` could be involved in the reopening of the form

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand what is issue but if you are not getting value of “FormResult”

It doesn’t matter if you close from but it will be better to set DialogResult before closing it, cause you are showing it as dialog (showdialog)

Verify that diaAddLocation is instance of you window not the window class directly
If name of you form is frmdiaAddLocation then do not use it like

```
frmdiaAddLocation.showdialog
```

use it like

```
Dim diaAddLocation AS  frmdiaAddLocation = New frmdiaAddLocation()
diaAddLocation.ShowDialog()
```

only using like this way will provide you result value

Comment: I am getting the result, the problem is that getting the result is reopening the form, I will have a look at what you have said and see if it helps.